# Pointer type casting to different data type

Tags: c, pointers, casting

what does `(float*)` specially do in case of g. If I write `g = *&i;`  then the ouptut is normal i.e. g=f, but if  `g = *(float*)&i;` then why is g=0.0000???

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{

int i = 37;
int *p;
p = &i;
float f = i;
printf("%d\n", i);
printf("%d\n", p);
printf("%d\n", *p);
float g = *(float*) &i;
printf("i = %d   f = %f   g = %f", i, f, g);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`g = *&i` is the same as `g = i` and is assignment of an int into a float. The compiler performs a conversion through the `=` operator:

1. Load integer, 2. convert as floating point format, 3. store in float. Works great beside the rounding problems.

The other construction is reinterpreting an integer pointer to a float pointer. Since data formats are different for floats (float is generally using some bits for mantissa and some bits for exponent) and for ints (ints are just serialized to memory 8-bit by 8-bit), the compiler just copies the data from source to destination without any extra conversion and you don't get what you want.

Comment: what is "reinterpreting an integer pointer to a float pointer" and how is it different from "assignment of an int into a float"

Comment: `int` to `float` assignment can lose significance if the `int` value is >= 2**24.

Comment: edited with more details. @WeatherVane okay (I understand 24 better than 16).

Comment: I edited comment, originally said 16 bit because there isn't AFAIK a 24-bit `int` type.

Comment: you mean: mantissa+sign is on 24 bits, exponent is on 8 bits: loss of precision makes sense.

Comment: Mantissa is 23 explicit bits, the 24th bit is implied (always 1 due to normalisation except when the value is 0).

Answer (score 0):

In the line:

```
g = *&i;
```

the operators `*` and `&` cancel each other out, so the result is as if the code was:

```
g = i;
```

---

The line:

```
float g = *(float*) &i;
```

causes undefined behavior because the types int and float are not compatible.

The result you're seeing is caused by undefined behavior, although in your case the behavior is relatively benign. What happens is that the bits of variable of type int are reinterpreted as if it were of type float.

Casting trough a pointer is not the correct way to interpret bits of a different type.